# Post to wall - Stream Error with Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, api, facebook-graph-api

Using the Actionscript API, I am receiving the following IOError

```
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://graph.facebook.com/********/feed"]
```

I am using the following code :

```
package  
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
import flash.system.Security;

public class Test extends Sprite
{

    public function Test() 
    {
        Security.allowDomain("*.facebook.com");
        Security.allowDomain("profile.ak.fbcdn.net");
        Security.allowDomain("static.ak.fbcdn.net");
        Security.allowDomain("graph.facebook.com");

        Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");

        Security.loadPolicyFile("http://graph.facebook.com/crossdomain.xml");

        Facebook.init("************", initHandler);

        var permissions:Array = ['publish_stream'];
        Facebook.login( loginHandler, { perms:permissions.join(',') } );
    }

    private function loginHandler(success:Object,fail:Object):void 
    { 
        trace("loginHandler success ="+success);
        trace("loginHandler fail    ="+fail);

        if(success)
        { 
            Facebook.api('/me/', handleMeLoad);
        } 
        else
        { 
            trace("unable to connect to Facebook");
        }
    }

    private function handleMeLoad(response:Object, fail:Object):void 
    {
        if (response) 
        {
            trace("response.first_name = "+response.first_name);
            trace("response.last_name = "+response.last_name);
            trace("response.id "+response.id);

            var values:Object = {
                                message:"MESSAGE"
                                };

            Facebook.api('/'+response.id+'/feed', handlePostComplete, values, "POST");
        }
    }

    private function initHandler(success:Object,fail:Object):void 
    {
        trace("initHandler response = "+success);
        trace("initHandler fail = "+fail);
    }

    private function handlePostComplete(response:Object, fail:Object)
    {
        trace("handlePostToFriendsWallComplete response "+response);
        trace("handlePostToFriendsWallComplete fail "+fail);
    }
}
```

}

(with all the fb vars as Strings)

using Flash player 10.

Comment: That error is due to the page being blocked somehow. Have you tried to call the URL directly in a browser?

Comment: Yep the problem was FB blacklisted my IP it seems...very nice of them not to tell me and waste a days work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Facebook blacklisted my IP / Account.  They could have at least told me... very unhelpfull

Answer (score 0):

The line facebook.init is incorrectly stated.
Whilst the documentation for the Actionscript implentation of the FB API is horrendous, you can get some pointers from the J(s)DK.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Facebook.init/